# Rollback Get Latest on TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, team-explorer

I had some changes on my local file but by mistake I took latest version from TFS. Now my changes have been lost. What can I do to take my unchange copy back? Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. If you didn't commit your changes, they're gone.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you added your previous changes to a shelveset (which is unlikely, otherwise you'd know they're there), your changes are gone.

Further reading, in case you don't know what a shelveset is:

- [What is shelving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556981/what-is-shelving-in-tfs-just-a-soft-checkin-so-others-can-see-code)
- [What is the purpose of a shelveset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338751/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-shelveset)

Answer (score 0):

Though Daniel's answer is perfect one for the question, I want to share something with others who might face the same situation as mine. As I got latest version from TFS, new files were giving giving compilation errors hence there was change in source files but not in dlls. After surfing around I have found [ILSpy link](http://ilspy.net/) which helped to to recover my source code.